# ¿Por qué se me suman los puntajes? bucle for JS

Tags: javascript

Mi consigna es hacer un juego de dados de dos jugadores, que tiren los dados por turnos y sólo sumen puntos con aquellos números impares.

Logré resolver la parte de que tiren los dados por separado, y puedo almacenar dichos números impares en un array `puntos_j1`, **el problema** es que luego de eso quiero sumarlos y guardarlos en otro array para que cuando se terminen 5 rondas pueda comparar resultados. Se guardan en un array  `sumaRonda1_j1` pero se suman los resultados de cada vuelta y me dan números muy elevados.

```js
var jugador1 = 0;
var jugador2 = 0;
var numero = new Array();
var puntos_j1 = new Array();
var puntos_j2 = new Array();
var sumaRonda1_j1 = new Array();
var sumaj1 = 0;
var sumaRonda1_j2 = new Array();
var sumaj2 = 0;
var i = 0;

function iniciodejuego() {

  //document.datos.ronda1.disabled=false;
  document.datos.jugador_1.disabled = false;
}

function jugadorUno() {
  document.datos.tiro1j1.disabled = false;
  document.datos.tiro2j1.disabled = false;
  document.datos.tiro3j1.disabled = false;
}

function primerTiro_j1() {


  for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

    numero[0] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd1").src = "img/" + numero[0] + ".png";
    numero[1] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd2").src = "img/" + numero[1] + ".png";
    numero[2] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd3").src = "img/" + numero[2] + ".png";

  }
  //si son impares que se sumen al total


  if (numero[0] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[0]);
  }


  if (numero[1] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[1]);
  }


  if (numero[2] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[2]);
  }

}

function segundoTiro_j1() {

  for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

    numero[3] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd1").src = "img/" + numero[3] + ".png";
    numero[4] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd2").src = "img/" + numero[4] + ".png";
    numero[5] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd3").src = "img/" + numero[5] + ".png";

  }
  //si son impares que se sumen al total
  if (numero[3] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[3]);

  }

  if (numero[4] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[4]);
  }

  if (numero[5] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[5]);
  }

}

//TRUE DESHABILITA
//FALSE HABILITA

function tercerTiro_j1() {

  for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

    numero[6] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd1").src = "img/" + numero[6] + ".png";
    numero[7] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd2").src = "img/" + numero[7] + ".png";
    numero[8] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("bd3").src = "img/" + numero[8] + ".png";

  }
  //si son impares que se sumen al total
  if (numero[6] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[6]);

  }
  if (numero[7] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[7]);
  }
  if (numero[8] % 2 == 1) {
    puntos_j1.push(numero[8]);
  }

  document.datos.jugador_2.disabled = false;
  document.datos.jugador_1.disabled = true;
  document.datos.tiro1j1.disabled = true;
  document.datos.tiro2j1.disabled = true;
  document.datos.tiro3j1.disabled = true;
  ssuma1();

}

function ssuma1() {
  for (i = 0; i < puntos_j1.length; i++) {
    sumaj1 = sumaj1 + puntos_j1[i];
  }
  sumaRonda1_j1.push(sumaj1);
}
```

```html
<form name="datos" id="datos">

  <input type="button" name="inicio" value="INICIAR JUEGO" onclick="iniciodejuego()"><br><br>

  <p>Jugador 1</p>
  <input type="number" name="resul_ronda1" id="ronda-1">
  <input type="button" name="ronda1" value="Ronda nº1" onclick="ronda_1_j1()" disabled><br>

  <input type="number" name="resul_ronda2" id="ronda-2">
  <input type="button" name="ronda2" value="Ronda nº2" onclick="" disabled><br>

  <input type="number" name="resul_ronda3" id="ronda-3">
  <input type="button" name="ronda3" value="Ronda nº3" onclick="" disabled><br>

  <input type="number" name="resul_ronda4" id="ronda-4">
  <input type="button" name="ronda4" value="Ronda nº4" disabled><br>

  <input type="number" name="resul_ronda5" id="ronda-5">
  <input type="button" name="ronda5" value="Ronda nº5" disabled><br><br>

  <!-- JUGADOR 1 -->

  <input type="button" name="jugador_1" value="Jugador 1" onclick="jugadorUno()" disabled> <br>

  <input type="button" name="tiro1j1" value="Primer tiro" onclick="primerTiro_j1()" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" name="tiro2j1" value="Segundo tiro" onclick="segundoTiro_j1()" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" name="tiro3j1" value="Tercer tiro" onclick="tercerTiro_j1()" disabled> <br><br>

  <!-- JUGADOR 2 -->

  <input type="button" name="jugador_2" value="Jugador 2" onclick="jugadorDos()" disabled><br><br>

  <input type="button" name="tiro1j2" value="Primer tiro" onclick="primerTiro_j2()" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" name="tiro2j2" value="Segundo tiro" onclick="segundoTiro_j2()" disabled><br>

  <input type="button" name="tiro3j2" value="Tercer tiro" onclick="tercerTiro_j2()" disabled> <br><br>



  <button type="button" value="Reset Form" onclick="document.location.reload(true)">Resetear</button>

</form>

<!--DADOS
 NO OLVIDAR: los dados tienen size 100x100px 
-->



<p><img src="img/0.png" width="70" height="70" alt="" id="bd1"></p>
<p><img src="img/0.png" width="70" height="70" alt="" id="bd2"></p>
<p><img src="img/0.png" width="70" height="70" alt="" id="bd3"></p>
```

**HTML**

Foto para que se entienda mejor: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se almacenan los puntajes pero cuando los sumo con el ciclo for se suman de forma repetida. Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias!

Comment: Tienes varios bucles `for` que no hacen nada (el contenido se ejecuta siempre una vez, solamente). Intenta limpiar el código que no uses

Comment: ¿A qué bucles te refieres? Los que están dentro de las variables que se llaman `primerTiro` son los que generan los puntos de la tirada de dados. @PabloLozano

Comment: Bucles con `for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {...` Si i empieza valiendo uno, la segunda iteración no ocurre.

Comment: Me está costando seguir la dinámica del juego: pulso iniciar juego, luego jugador 1, luego puedo pulsar primer tiro N veces, segundo tiro igual... pero tercer tiro una vez. y si pulso jugador 2 falla porque faltan funciones. ¿Puedes explicar qué pasos das?

Comment: @PabloLozano Gracias por tomarte el tiempo. Los pasos serían los siguientes:
1- pulsar Iniciar juego: se habilita el botón de jugador 1
2- Pulso Jugador 1: se habilitan las opciones de tiro 1, tiro 2, tiro 3. Cuando se pulsan los botones se van tirando los tres dados y se almacenan los números impares en la variable `puntos_j1`.
3- Cuando el jugador 1 realiza el tercer tiro sucenden dos cosas: por un lado se habilita la tirada de dados para el jugador 2 y por otro lado, deberían sumarse los puntos almacenados en `puntos_j1` para poder guardar el puntaje de cada ronda. Eso no me sale

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y añade los pasos en la pregunta, será mejor

Comment: Esta es la función es la que 'se supone' yo debería poder ir sumando los puntos obtenidos por cada jugador pero, como se ve en la imagen del posteo, repite la suma de las rondas. Si el jugador1 saco 15 puntos en su primer tirada de dados, en la segunda me muestra que sumo 51 cuando en realidad saco 16. 

`function ssuma1() {
  for (i = 0; i < puntos_j1.length; i++) {
    sumaj1 = sumaj1 + puntos_j1[i];
  }
  sumaRonda1_j1.push(sumaj1);
}`

Comment: Cuando pulsas jugador 2 falla porque borre esas funciones ya que es el mismo código repetido de Tiros que hace el jugador 1. 
Cómo no logro acumular el puntaje no puedo seguir avanzando en el juego

Comment: creo que debes reiniciar a cero sumaj1 cada vez que llamas a la función ssuma1

Comment: Oh gracias!!! Con poner sumaj1 = 0 dentro de la función ssuma1 se almacena en la última posición del array. Muchas gracias!!